# (None) Value on Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I created a list in Sharepoint where one of the columns looks for values from another list.

I'm using this list in Microsoft Teams to be populated, but when I select the corresponding column field, the first option that appears is (None).

This field is required, but is it possible to remove this option (None)?
[image: example]

Even if someone tries to select this option the list warns that "You can't leave this blank", but I still would like to remove this option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your 'source column' that contains your values.  Then filter on the blanks; add values to the blank items.

Then in your 'other column' that re-uses these values you will find that the option `(none)` has disappeared.  In your source column, you can change the column settings to make it a Required field - this way users will not leave it blank.

Comment: Hi @Tally, In fact, I made a mistake: I created a list in Sharepoint where one of the columns looks for values from another **list**, not from another column.

Comment: OK, well the advice remains the same - can you go to the source list, find the column which you are using for your look-up column values; then filter on the blanks and fill in values there?  There are 3rd party look-up columns (Sparqube is the name) that allow you to filter out blanks, but the standard ones will not permit this.  Even a "blank" value is a value, hence it is normal that your look-up shows the (none) option.

Comment: What a shame. I will have to live with (none) then :(

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint online, when create a lookup column, it is by designer that there will be "None" option in modern experience, it cannot be removed in modern experience.

If we set the lookup column as a required column, there is no "None" option in classic experience.